# what is 'st' the param in ganglia web url

Tags: ganglia

i redirected to this url when i want json data from graph

http://xx.xx.xx.xx/ganglia/graph.php?c=my%20cluster&h=compute1&r=custom&z=default&jr=&js=&st=1467782481&cs=06%2F01%2F2016%2000%3A00&ce=06%2F30%2F2016%2000%3A00&v=100.00&m=pphjditimis2157.vmem_util&vl=%25&ti=pphjditimis2157%3A%20VM%20Memory%20Utilization&json=1

what is st parameter in the above url ?

Answer (score 0):

```
st (source time) [Does not seem to be in use]
Current time of data source (in UNIX time)
```

https://github.com/ganglia/monitor-core/wiki/Web-GET-Vars.

From a wiki on Ganglia.